# How do I display the displayName in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was able to save the displayName to the user in Firebase, but I am not sure how to display that name on the page in JS.

Currently, I am using this:

```
document.getElementById('txtName').innerHTML = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if your element is correctly identified and display it to the console.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('txtName'));
```

The Firebase syntax is ok, just check the user against null, like:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, output;
output = document.getElementById("txtName");

if (user != null) {
  name = user.displayName;
  output.innerHTML= name;
}
```